# desmos.com graph only goes from -π/2 το +π/2

Tags: trigonometry, approximation

Here is my graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l8o2bapufk

If you do not want to visit the link, here is a screenshot:

[image]

The dashed line is the built-in sin(x) function.

The superimposed orange line is an approximation function.

## My question is:

Why is desmos only plotting the part between -π/2 and +π/2 ?

I would have expected the orange line to extend over all of the dashed line, covering it entirely.

The other two approximation functions (hidden away in folders) do not suffer from this problem.

<sub>(I tried adding a desmos.com tag, but apparently I need to have 1000 rep to add a new tag.)</sub>

## A recap of the answer:

As Michael Riberdy answered, the graph does not end there where it seems to end, it continues waaaay out of the screen, so you have to zoom out a lot (or zoom to fit) in order to see it.

As Troposphere wrote in a comment, the discontinuity is due to a faulty term, and the fault is mine.  The original code was:

> `x -= 0.25 + Math.floor( x + 0.25 );`

and I naively transcribed this as

> f<sub>33</sub>(x) = x - 0.25 + floor( x + 0.25 )

while in fact I should have of course transcribed it as

> f<sub>33</sub>(x) = x - 0.25 - floor( x + 0.25 )

due to operator precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to zoom out to see the rest.

Comment: oh my goodness, I did try zooming out, but I did not try zooming out ***so much!***

Comment: @MikeNakis: Looks like the $\mathrm{floor}(x+0.25)$ term in $f_{33}$ is a deliberate misdirection -- its only effect is to kick the graph far out of the way outside the interval where it looks like the sine curve. Or perhaps it's a transcription error -- if you _subtract_ it instead of adding it, it approximation becomes periodic!

Comment: @Troposphere you are right! That's very perceptive of you, thank you very much!  I updated the question to explain what happened.